# What is the name of this plant/stem/flower and where can I find more of it

Tags: identification, stems

[image]

I’m trying to find more of this stem that I found at Trader joe’s but they couldn’t tell me the name of it.

Comment: a better picture and a closeup picture would help....

Answer (score 4):

This is a cultivar of Sweet William (*Dianthus barbatus*). There are several cultivars with similar green "flowers", including  'Green Ball' and 'Green Trick.' Sweet William is closely related to the carnation ([*Dianthus caryophyllus*](https://www.gardenia.net/plant/dianthus-barbatus-green-ball)), which is why the stem looks a lot like the stem of a carnation.

[image]
Dianthus barbatus 'Green Ball' ([image source](https://www.gardenia.net/plant/dianthus-barbatus-green-ball))

[image]
Dianthus barbatus 'Green Trick' ([image source](https://www.gardenersworld.com/plants/dianthus-barbatus-green-trick/))

To get more of it, you can order online from someplace that sells floral supplies - look for a place that is geared towards DIY floral arrangements for weddings or other events, rather than someplace that only sells pre-made bouquets. You may find them by searching "green trick flowers," "green ball flowers," "green dianthus flowers," etc. If the supplier website is organized by categories, these will be in a "filler flower" or "greenery" section. Or ask a local florist; if they have this in stock to use in their flower arrangements they will probably be willing to sell you a few stems.